# Specifying Column Name with SQL AS via BookshelfJS

Tags: bookshelf.js

How do I make use of the SQL `AS` with Bookshelf? e.g.

```
SELECT tableName.thatColumn AS thisColumn FROM tableName
```

Tried to do via `withRelated` but Bookshelf disapproved.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out: The Knex `QueryBuilder` exposes a `column` method. However, they don't explicitly explain how to invoke the SQL `AS` keyword but do illustrate an example for how to do it:

http://knexjs.org/#Builder-as

e.g.

```
qb.column('thisName as thatName')
```